# Split Jquery.ajax returned data

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#populateNav").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
                        data: "Name=David",
                        url: "Fetchdata.aspx",
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#data").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

The "data" returned from fetchdata.aspx is a string array.

Is there a way to split the array and put those string in 3 different places ()??

The returned data is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String []data = new string[3];
        data[0] = "New York";
        data[1] = "01914";
        data[2] = "111-111-1111";

        Response.Write(data);


        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Probably is, but how should we know without seeing what's returned in the Ajax call ?

Comment: Can you please post the string value returned in `data`.

Comment: use var part1 = data.split('separator')[1] if you can use a separator of course...